# Python - colorplot that takes average of grid-corners?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am having a bit of struggle to find a plotting method. I have the below shown grid with values (1's and 0's):

[image]

When I plot this with pcolormesh or imshow from the matplotlib.pyplot library I get this plot:

[image]

Which makes sense, but is not what I want. I want to take the corners of a grid cell and find the average to fill that cell. It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

I can do the average calculations by hand but I was wondering if anyone knows of an existing plotting method that does this, or if it is available as an option in pcolormesh?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the average of a grid you need to calculate that average. In the simplest case,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,0,0],
              [1,0,0]])

plt.pcolormesh( (a[:-1, :-1] + a[1:, :-1] + a[:-1, 1:] + a[1:, 1:])/4. )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is a faster method than I used (with a nested for-loop). So I think there is no direct method in matplotlib.pyplot for doing this?

Comment: No there is no inbuilt method for averaging a grid. There are just some inbulit filters, https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html, which are handy, but not for this case.